# Why are monocotyledonous plants considered more evolved than dicotyledonous?

Tags: evolution, botany

Why are the following characteristics advantageous for a plant?

- to have atactostele instead of eustele
- to have less stamens
- to lose secondary growth
- to switch to anemophily pollination (also if it's not always the case)
- to use the cotyledon as storage media instead of endosperm

Why are there so much similarities between liliopsida and gymnospermae?

Comment: This wasn't an homework question, but a genuine curiosity that arose studying such organisms. I'll be glad to modify it to fit the rules of the community if possible.